# link to a url in a table constructed out of an array

Tags: php, html

How can I make the $v->Url part from the code below do this:

```
<a href="Url">Link text</a>
```

So my cell doesn't 'explode' in case of a long url?

```
foreach($array as $k=>$v){
    print "
    <tr>      
      <td>" . $v->Status . "</td>
      <td>" . $v->Url . "</td>
    </tr>";
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to output a link in PHP in an echo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the link text is stored in a member var of `$v`. Try this:

```
foreach($array as $k=>$v){
    print "
    <tr>
      <td>{$v->Status}</td>
      <td><a href=\"{$v->Url}\">{$v->Text}</a></td>
    </tr>";
}
```

Of course you'll have to rename `$v->Text` if the member has a different name in your application.

Comment: perfect; I replaced {$v->Text} by the static text; "Link" so it became:
    <td><a href=\"{$v->Url}\">Link</a></td>